# Using ternary operator on Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I need to print some string based on the true or false of a condition.

For example:

```cs
    if(i == m) {
        Console.WriteLine("Number is valid");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Number is invalid");
    }
```

How can I check this condition and print a message using conditional operator and with only one `Console.WriteLine`?

I was trying:

```cs
    (i == m) ? Console.WriteLine("Number is valid") : Console.WriteLine("Number is not valid");
```

I know I'm doing it wrong here. Can someone please tell me the correct way?

Comment: And what is the exact problem you were having?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
    Console.WriteLine("Number is " + ((i == m) ? "valid" : "not valid"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old topic, but I wanted to add my two cents.

You can also use `string.Concat()` like below C# code

```
Console.Writeline(string.Concat("Number is ", (i == m) ? "valid" : "not valid"));
```

In my opinion, it is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Maybe, but the question was about using the ternary operator, not about string concatenation more broadly.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Well, OP wanted to know how to use only one `Console.WriteLine()` with ternary operator. I gave OP another way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

Move your ternary operation inside `WriteLine`

```
Console.WriteLine((i == m) ? "Number is valid" : "Number is not valid");
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator is an *operator*. It returns a value. The value it returns is the value from one of its branches.

`Console.WriteLine` is a `void` method. It does not return a value. As a result, you cannot use it as one of the branches of the conditional operator.

BTW, this operator is correctly called "the conditional operator". It happens to be *a* ternary operator, meaning that it is an operator which takes three parameters.
ere
It runs:

1. Unary
2. Binary
3. Ternary
4. Quaternary

etc.

There happens to be only a single ternary operator in C# at present - the conditional operator.
There happen to be no quaternary or higher-order operators.