# C# Console Create simple app not longer than 2 lines

Tags: c#, console

Hello Guys i am new here so hope to have fun together my teacher asked me to do a simple app just for that ( when the user enter number "1" it writes "2" when enter "2" it writes "1" ) i am with you that is to easy for using if or switch case but she told me to not to exceed two lines
please anybody help  i am sucked

Comment: Look into [ternary operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258975/using-ternary-operator-on-console-writeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is use a ternary operator inside another ternary operator.
It does the job in two lines.

```
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine((input == "1") ? ("2") : (input == "2" ? "1" : "Enter 1 or 2"));
```

Comment: oh thanks my bro but the app closes immediately aftert that how can i make it last longer until i close it manually ?!

Comment: That's the nature of such simple console apps - they do the job and automatically close themselves.
To keep the application open, you can add Console.ReadLine() or Console.ReadKey() at the end. The application will then do the job and wait for an additional keyboard press.